# ASP.NET MVC4 custom formatting method for Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model, custom-formatting

```
 <div>
Email: 
<a id="email href="mailto:@Model.Contact.Email">@Model.Contact.Email.ToStringMyCustomFormatted</a>
</div>
```

I want to create custom method for formatting and apply it like this. 
(in the same way we can apply ToString() method to this.)
I don't want to use JavaScript to do any formatting by using Document.Ready().
In short I want to extend ToString method something like ToStringMyCustomFormatted, by which I can apply my own rules to string output.
I am not even sure if something like can be done. 
Please Enlighten !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple C# extension method (or directly on your Contact model):

```
public static class YourContactModelExtensions {
    public static string ToStringMyCustomFormat(this YourContactModel m) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

or if you wanted it to apply to all strings:

```
public static class StringExtensions {
    public static string ToMyCustomFormat(this string s) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

or a Razor helper function on your Razor page:

```
@helper ToStringMyCustomFormat(YourContactModel m) {
   @* TODO *@
}
```

or

```
@helper ToMyCustomFormat(string s) {
   @* TODO *@
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... ! I am following this link : 
 [How to: Implement and Call a Custom Extension Method (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042.aspx)

Comment: Just one problem: the extension should be to `String` not to `Contact`, since the method is being called off of the `Email` property, not the instance directly.